# How is conditional probability calculated when conditioning over a variable?

Tags: conditional-probability

This is from Daphne Koller's video lectures.

[image]

I don't understand how the probabilities are calculated for the middle table P(S,G | i0). I tried adding rows of s0 and g1 but it doesn't add up whether I condition on i0 or marginalize on i0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the first 6 Probs to get $\Pr\{I=i^0\}$, which is 0.6. Then dividing the first 6 Probs by 0.6, you get the conditional probabilities presenting in the middle table. For example, $\Pr\{S=s^0, G=g^1|I=i^0\} = 0.114/0.6 = 0.19$